# Boot and Install Windows from a USB thumb drive

Tags: windows, installation, usb-flash-drive

Installing Windows from a thumb drive is vastly superior to burning a copy to a DVD which will fill some landfill somewhere with toxic stuff. Not to mention it's about 50x faster to install Windows from a USB Thumb Drive.

How do you get the bits onto the thumb drive so that you can boot from it and do a clean install?

Comment: Thanks Omar, I found your question after typing in the title to my own question. Was looking for Windows 2008, but they'll all be the same.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Update: Microsoft has created the [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) to make this very easy.

I used this guide as a set of directions - http://kurtsh.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!DA410C7F7E038D!1665.entry

**1. Get a USB Thumbdrive between 4-32GB.**

If the drive is larger than 32GB, Windows cannot format it as FAT32, so an alternate utility must be used. Windows can still *read* FAT32 partitions larger than 32GB, though some devices cannot.

**2. Run `cmd.exe` as administrator and enter the following commands followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>**

1. `diskpart`
2. `list disk`
3. `select disk #` (where *#* is your USB drive as determined from step 2)
4. `clean` **(This step will delete all data on your flash drive!)**
5. `create partition primary`
6. `active`
7. `format fs=fat32 quick`
8. `assign`
9. `list volume`
10. `exit`
11. `bootsect.exe /nt60 F: /mbr` (where `F:` is the drive letter of your USB drive as reported by `list volume`)

**3. Copy the Windows files from the ISO or other source using robocopy**

```
robocopy.exe E:\ F:\ /MIR
```

where `E:\` is the source and `F:\` is the destination. Drag-and-drop or copy/paste can also be used, if you know what you're doing.

**Configure your PC to boot from the USB drive**

In some machines the USB thumbdrive will appear to the BIOS as any other hard drive. You need to muck with the boot sequence to place the thumbdrive higher in the boot order than the local hard drive.

> Note that after you do this you might
>   want to reset the boot order in order
>   to ensure that BitLocker doesn't
>   detect boot changes based on the fact
>   that the thumdrive is missing if it
>   was there when you encrypted your
>   drive.

Comment: Performed this today from within Win7, and Robocopy did not like the Fat32 filesystem (constant Error 87). Formatting as NTFS did the trick. Thanks for the writeup!

Comment: thanks for the tip, I changed it to NTFS in the format command

Comment: 'format fs=ntfs quick' to quick format which takes significantly less time than a full format

Comment: I tried this, but now I always get an error message while booting with the stick: "Couldn't find NTLDR" when I formatted it with NTFS or "Remove disks or other media" when I formatted it with FAT. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I'm not mistaking Step 2.2 "select disk 1" is not always disk 1.

Comment: I think, [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) is still a better option.

Comment: @mmdemirbas I also would think so especially since the 10 steps are missing any procedure to actually equip the drive with a boot loader so far, so the resulting USB drive would not boot. And the USB/DVD download tool only would work for Windows 7.

Comment: Note that if you are creating Winddows XP bootable drive, then you should use bootsect /nt52 instead /nt60

Comment: There is this tool for windows 10:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install

Comment: After going through these instructions (unsuccessfully) myself a few years ago, I've updated it with correct, working instructions.

Comment: As p.campbell mentioned, choosing NTFS instead FAT32 is the way to go on Error 87. The reason is a file with size > 4GiB on the installation CD which can't be copied to FAT32.

Comment: On Windows 10, the command "E:\ F:\ /MIR" didn't work.  "E: F: /MIR" did.  Also, robocopy on Windows 10 will balk at spaces in the path for source or destination and doesn't understand putting quotes around a path that has spaces in it. Finally, if your source is an .iso file, it must be mounted first.

Answer (score 16):

I found two problems with the accepted answer:

1. It assumes the usb drive is disk 1 for DISKPART.
   This can be resolved by using the LIST DISK command prior to SELECT DISK # to determine the correct disk number.
2. The usb drive did not appear as a bootable device to the target machine.
   This can be fixed by running the bootsect utility off the Windows installation DVD.

   Before copying the contents of the Windows DVD:

   1. Run cmd.exe as Administrator
   2. Select your optical drive (assumed to be D:)
   3. Type `CD boot`
   4. Type `D:\boot\bootsect.exe /nt60 U:` (where U: is your USB drive)

Adding these extra steps I was able to install Windows 7 from a USB HDD onto a Samsung NC10 Netbook.

If this proves unsuccessful some other techniques (including the accepted answer with the above steps) can be found at http://www.bootdisk.com/pendrive.htm.

Answer (score 10):

There is a tool **([YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/))** to achieve this. I think, it is **fastest** and **painless** way of preparing a (multi)bootable usb. You can put **many systems** (Windows, Linux, HBCD etc.) into one flash drive. And you can also use an **external drive**.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/)

> Rufus is an utility that helps format and create bootable USB flash
>   drives, such as USB keys/pendrives, memory sticks, etc.
>
> It can be especially useful for cases where:
>
> - you need to create USB installation media from bootable ISOs (Windows, Linux, UEFI, etc.)
> - you need to work on a system that doesn't have an OS installed
> - you need to flash a BIOS or other firmware from DOS
> - you want to run a low-level utility
>
> Despite its small size, Rufus provides everything you need!

Answer (score 1):

Quick tip I hope will help people going through the same pain as me when trying to create a thumb drive for Windows Server 2008

I had an old USB led around, but it wouldn't mount for me to run `diskpart` on it.

Turns out it was formatted in FAT16. Mount it on a laptop with a proper OS, reformat it to FAT32, then plug it back into the Windows Server 2008 box and it mounts. Then run `diskpart` as above.

Answer (score 0):

Use MultiSystem if you're creating the USB drive from linux.

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.