# Installing Windows 7 RC on Mac OS X

Tags: windows-7, mac-osx, usb

Is it possible to use the Bootcamp Assistant to install Windows 7 RC on Mac OS X?

Also, how do I install/boot from usb after copying the iso to the usb harddrive??

Answer (score 3):

Booting from USB, for non OSX os's does not work by default with Macbooks and Macbook Pros. It is possible to do however (I have done it). You have to install [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) in OSx, this gives you extra boot time options, including installing from USB. Once it is installed, reboot your mac and hold down option as usuall. You should then see rEFIt as a boot choice, select that and you should then have access to the USB stick.

This said, you cannot just copy the ISO to a USB stick to install, you need to follow the instructions below to create a bootable USB drive:

1. On windows Vista or XP type the following at the command prompt:
2. diskpart
3. type “list disk” and you will see all connected disks and numbers
4. select disk X (X being the number of the usb disk )
5. clean
6. create partition primary
7. select partition 1
8. active
9. format fs=fat32
10. assign
11. exit

You now have a bootable USB drive. Now extract the files from the ISO to the USB drive, and boot as above.

Comment: That means.... if I want to boot from usb hd, I will have to find a Vista to create a bootable USB drive? so much hassle...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake Diskpart should be in XP as well

Comment: You can use these instructions for creating a bootable USB drive. http://serverfault.com/questions/2952/boot-and-install-windows-from-a-usb-thumb-drive/2954#2954

Answer (score 1):

Yes, works a treat, use the Vista drivers. Not sure you can boot from USB, someone will answer that one properly.