# Win 7 Error - No disk in the drive

Tags: windows-7

I installed Windows 7 RC 1 from a usb flash drive using [these directions](https://serverfault.com/questions/2952/boot-and-install-windows-from-a-usb-thumb-drive).  The installation went well, however when I log into the laptop I'm getting the error message:

"There is no disk in the drive.  Please insert a disk into drive \Device\Harddisk3\DR3"

I've put the thumb drive back in thinking it needed to finish the installation, but that hasn't changed anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was the windows logon scripts used to attach to the network drives.

I went into disk management, and there were two drive letter being used although no drives were attached, meaing drive letter G: and H: were set aside to be used by removable media, although the media wasn't available.

I've seen a similar error in Win XP, but usually only when the drives are currently being used.

I hope this helps anyone who runs across the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when launching Miranda IM on a Vista x64 System. Your answer definately helped me in tracking down the problem.
It wasn't a network drive that was not ready but a drive letter that was used by my USB Card reader but did not have a card in it. After I removed the drive letter from disk management Miranda worked like a charm!